# Base 64 CSS background image not showing in IE

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to make a base 64 encoded CSS image show in IE?

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...
```

Currently the image does not appear in IE.

#### Update

I used

```
img{behavior:expression((this.runtimeStyle.behavior="none")&&(/^data:.*;base64/i.test(this.src))&&(this.src="/my/base64.php?"+this.src.slice(5)));}
```

per [dean](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-sexy/) in my css and turned my css background image into an img tag, as dean's solution only supports img tags.

It failed with a `PNG-24`, but was successful with a `PNG-8`

I am converting graphics with [this tool](http://www.writeitstudios.com/cssencode.html) for mac.

Comment: Any specific version of IE? Which versions have you been testing in?

Comment: Tested in 6, 7, and 8 - Works great in all other browsers

Comment: id put a fair amount on money on saying that this doesn't work before IE8

Comment: I believe IE8 can handle this for the regular img tag, if the encoded image is 32KiB or less in size ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some methods [described here](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/) for mimicking the same kind of behaviour in IE.

If you're interested in using Javascript to get IE to conform, there's some [useful information here on Dean Edwards site](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-sexy/).

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not support base64 encoded images. There are [plenty of workarounds](http://www.google.com/search?q=base64%20encoded%20images%20internet%20explorer), though.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, dude this will not work in versions IE less than 8:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support